# How to add pattern to GeoJson shape on a React-Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using [React-Leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/) to display a [Leaflet.js](https://leafletjs.com/) map. I use [React-Leaflet GeoJSON](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/components.html#geojson) ([source here](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/GeoJSON.js)) to show a layer of polygons on the map.

Although I can vary the opacity of the fill (`fillOpacity`) of the polygon, I cannot find an option to fill the polygon with a pattern (e.g. checkers, stripes, etc.)

I have found a project ([Leaflet.pattern](https://github.com/teastman/Leaflet.pattern)) that supports adding fill patterns to `Leaflet.js` shapes, but it has not been adapted for use with `React-Leaflet`.

So my question is: How can I add patterns to `React-Leaflet` shapes, or adapt `Leaflet.pattern` for use with `React-Leaflet`? (for the latter, instructions on how to create custom `React-Leaflet` components are [here](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html), but I don't know how to do it for this case - it seems more complex than usual)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [section in the docs about extending react-leaflet](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/en/custom-components.html)

If you are using react-leaflet v1 you can directly extend react-leaflet's GeoJSON class. If you are using v2 you'll need to extend the [Path](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/blob/master/src/Path.js) class instead. To understand why that's necessary take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506).

Once you've figured out which class to extend it's likely that most of your changes will need to happen in the `createLeafletElement`function and maybe the `updateLeafletElement` function.